# Logistic Regression - Adding a polynomial basis to my input matrix make sense?

Tags: machine-learning, logistic, polynomial

When I tried to run logistic regression on a 1500 X 35 input matrix, I obtained an error of 0.23 with 0 -1 loss. Then, I tried to add a polynomial basis of degree 2 or 3 to my matrix, which can be represented now like:

$$1, X_1, X_1^2, X^3, X_2, X_2^2, ... X_N^3$$

I obtained 0.16 with degree 3 and 0.19 with degree 2 on my test error after running 10-fold cross validation.

So the thing is I obtained a better result for sure, but I am wondering if adding a polynomial basis makes sense? Am I not corrupting my data here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get an idea why this can occur, take a look at [these notes](http://www.holehouse.org/mlclass/06_Logistic_Regression.html) on logistic regression. (They appear to be from Andrew Ng's open course on machine learning; the associated videos may also prove helpful.) In brief, using a polynomial function of your predictive features allows you to fit a non-linear, more expressive decision boundary. Your better performance suggests that the data are better separated this third-order polynomial boundary.

I'm not sure what you mean by "corrupt." Using a function of your data is acceptable feature selection. Fitting a more complex boundary runs the risk of overfitting, but that's why one examines test error, which you've already mentioned checking.